# package ‘tidyverse’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the "tidyverse" package and I get the following warning:

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyverse’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

I can install each package individually, but who wants to do it again and again..!
should I install the older version of R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need a newer not older version of R so update R and you should be good to go.

Comment: Correct; R 3.2.2 released [August 2015](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/), tidyverse [September 2016](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tidyverse/). It' s generally best to have the latest R.